# How to ensure data is entered into the InputBox?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I am trying to make sure data is entered into the InputBox at each stage otherwise I want the message to pop-up and the entry to end.

I have a MsgBox that pops up if nothing is entered but I want to add an option to have the Sub remain at the InputBox so the user can still enter the data.

I've tried `vbRetryCancel` and either the Retry will loop and then never cancel (and I have to force Outlook to close to end the macro) or the Cancel will loop and it will never retry.

If I could make it so the InputBox would not advance with "Ok" until data is entered or "cancel" was clicked that would work too but I would still need a MsgBox if nothing is entered to alert the user.

```vb
Sub Request_Tracking()

    Dim objMsg As MailItem
    Dim tasksource As String
    Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    'requests input of the user with various options
    tasksource = InputBox("Please select task receipt method:" & _
        vbCrLf & vbTab & "1 - Phone call" & _
        vbCrLf & vbTab & "2 - Email" & _
        vbCrLf & vbTab & "3 - Instant Message" & _
        vbCrLf & vbTab & "4 - Desk walk-up" & _
        vbCrLf & vbTab & "5 - Miscellaneous", "Option Chooser")
    
    'if response is blank then ends the task
    If tasksource = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Nothing was entered. Please re-enter your request.", vbOKOnly, "Error!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
            
    Select Case tasksource
        Case "1"
            tasksource = "Phone call"
        Case "2"
            tasksource = "Email"
        Case "3"
            tasksource = "Instant Message"
        Case "4"
            tasksource = "Desk walk-up"
        Case "5"
            tasksource = "Miscellaneous"
        Case Else
            tasksource = tasksource
    End Select
    
    'various input boxes for data needed, if response is blank then ends the task without send
    strName = InputBox("Requestor Name:")
        If strName = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox "Nothing was entered. Please reattempt your request.", vbOKOnly, "Error"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    strCoreEvent = InputBox("Task Description:")
        If strCoreEvent = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox "Nothing was entered. Please reattempt your request.", vbOKOnly, "Error"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    strUnitNum = InputBox("Number of units:")
        If strUnitNum = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox "Nothing was entered. Please reattempt your request.", vbOKOnly, "Error"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    strTime = InputBox("Processing Time:")
        If strTime = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox "Nothing was entered. Please reattempt your request.", vbOKOnly, "Error"
            Exit Sub
        End If

    'configures message being sent, sents to WFM box and formats the body font and various line breaks and then sends
    With objMsg
        .To = "tracking@test.com"
        .Subject = "Request Received"
        .HTMLBody = "<body style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Arial><b>For request tracking; please assign to me.</b>" & "<p>" & tasksource & " request from " & strName & ": " & strCoreEvent & "<br />Number of units: " & strUnitNum & "<br />Processing time: " & strTime & "</p></body>"
        .Recipients.ResolveAll
        .Send
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to make it mandatory for the user to enter data in inputbox?

Comment: @PankajJaju yes I do. I am unsure how would be the easiest way to do that

Answer (score 2):

Your can try something like this:

```
While tasksource = " "
    tasksource = InputBox("Please select task receipt method:" & _
    vbCrLf & vbTab & "1 - Phone call" & _
    vbCrLf & vbTab & "2 - Email" & _
    vbCrLf & vbTab & "3 - Instant Message" & _
    vbCrLf & vbTab & "4 - Desk walk-up" & _
    vbCrLf & vbTab & "5 - Miscellaneous", "Option Chooser", " ")
    If tasksource = vbNullString Then
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf (tasksource = " ") Then
        tasksourceCancel = MsgBox("Nothing was entered. Please re-enter your request. Or press Cancel to leave!", vbOKCancel, "Error!")
        If tasksourceCancel = 2 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
Wend
```

It forces the user to have Input, if user clicks OK the return/default value will be `" " (space)` will loop, if the user clicks cancel the value will be `vbNullString` and it will exit.

Comment: That code works but the issue I am running into is if I click cancel on the InputBox then "tasksourceCancel" is still invoked. Is there a way to when the cancel button on the InputBox is pressed just exit the sub instead of having the extra step?

Comment: @jnjustice, check if that's more inline with what you'd want.

Comment: @miguelryu I think the prior code was more inline with what I am looking for because I think the alert would make more sense so the users know why there is an error. Is at as simple as adding an "else" fuction and including the cancel press on the inputbox?

Comment: @jnjustice You can still put the MsgBox inside the while (after `tasksource = vbNullString`) to promp the error message, would you like me to exemplify?

Comment: @jnjustice, you'll need to put an `else if(tasksource = " ")` or else the message will popup even if the `tasksource` has a value in it.

Comment: Note, `StrPtr(tasksource)` will be `0` if the user cancelled the inputbox, and that's always equal to `vbNullString`, so checking for `vbNullString` alone isn't good enough if cancellation needs to be distinguishable from an empty input. Making the default a single space seems a bit of a hack / work-around that. `If Trim(tasksource) = vbNullString` would be enough to know if input was empty, regardless of the default.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Do
    tasksource = InputBox("Please select task receipt method:" & _
            vbCrLf & vbTab & "1 - Phone call" & _
            vbCrLf & vbTab & "2 - Email" & _
            vbCrLf & vbTab & "3 - Instant Message" & _
            vbCrLf & vbTab & "4 - Desk walk-up" & _
            vbCrLf & vbTab & "5 - Miscellaneous", "Option Chooser", 1)
            If Not (tasksource >=1 And tasksource <=5) Then
                optionvar = MsgBox("Incorrect selection. Do you want to re-enter your request?", vbYesNo, "Input required")
                If optionvar = 6 Then 'if yes is pressed
                    tasksource = vbNullString
                Else
                    tasksource = optionvar
                End If
            End If
Loop While tasksource = vbNullString
```